# 'Multiple actions were found' error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have the following default routes setup for my web api services ...

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultControllerWithIdAndAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new {action = RouteParameter.Optional}
    );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultPost",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
    defaults: new { action = "Post" },
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) }
    );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultGetWithId",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "Get" },
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
    );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultPutWithId",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "Put" },
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Put) }
    );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultDeleteWithId",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "Delete" },
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Delete) }
    );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultControllerWithAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

I have the following services under 'UsersController':

```
public UserDto Get(string id){}

[HttpGet]
public UserDto ByEmail(string email)

[HttpGet]
public bool IsEmailUnique(string email)
```

The issue is that I am getting a 'Multiple actions were found' error when try to hit any of the three services.  The request should select the last route from all the routes and execute the request.

If I were to execute '/api/users/byemail?email=blah@blah.com', shouldn't know that 'ByEmail' is the action and using the method & the action, match the correct method?  I guess I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have mapped your BeEmail and IsEmailUnique methods to the GET action, which caused multiple actions to be found.

<s>Since you have already setup a routetemplate for named actions (DefaultControllerWithAction) you can remove the [HttpGet] attribute.</s>

<s>After this the routetemplate "DefaultControllerWithAction" should sort out  '/api/users/byemail' just fine</s>

**edit:** 
Seems there is an issue mixing traditional and verb-based routing in the same ApiController.
That's documented [here on codeplex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/184) and there is one blog post that claims to have solved this (not tested yet): 
http://blog.appliedis.com/2013/03/25/web-api-mixing-traditional-verb-based-routing/

**edit2:**
just tested this out and the solution from Kip Streithorst works out for your situation.

```
Step 1:hardcode a default value instead of specifying that action is optional.
Step 2:decorate your "verb-based controllers with the hardcoded default action name
```

For your get requests this would be:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultControllerWithAction",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { action = "DefaultAction }
        );
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultGetWithId",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "Get" },
        constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
        );
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultControllerWithIdAndAction",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
        defaults: new { action = "DefaultAction" }
        );
```

and

```
    [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
    public UserDto Get(string id){}

    [HttpGet]
    public UserDto ByEmail(string email)

    [HttpGet]
    public bool IsEmailUnique(string email)
```

Comment: I thought that the 'HttpGet' is needed to let the api know that the service expects a Get request only.  Otherwise, its a POST by default.

Comment: Doh... yes, my bad, sorry for that mistake. It seems there is an issue mixing traditional and verb-based routing in the same ApiController. That's documented here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/184 , and there is one blog post that claims to have solved this : 
http://blog.appliedis.com/2013/03/25/web-api-mixing-traditional-verb-based-routing/  Hope this helps more than my deadwrong answer..